# How to get HTML input fields of popup window populated from query-string variables passed from parent window using ASP classic

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp-classic

I'm creating an application in ASP classic, ASP.net and JavaScript in which I have two forms named 'update_status.asp' & 'Rate_Add.aspx'. Inside 'update_status.asp' I have a textbox when I click on this, the 'Rate_Add.aspx' form with some query string variables is opened in a popup window.

Now the question is I want to populate the textboxes of 'Rate_Add.aspx'using JavaScript with `querystrings` passed from 'update_status.asp' but I don't understand how I will differentiate if 'Rate_Add.aspx' form is opening in a popup or the form itself. Means the textboxes of 'Rate_Add.aspx' should be populated only when it is opening inside the popup, otherwise the original 'Rate_Add.aspx' should open empty.

Code in 'update_status.asp' is

```
var myWindow = window.open("rateadd.aspx?loggedin=yes&indate=<%=indate%>&outdate=<%=outdate%>&curr=" , "", "width=1200,height=600,toolbars=no,scrollbars,resizeable=no,left=50,top=50");
```

In 'Rate_Add.aspx' using JavaScript I am trying to retrieve those `querystring` values into textbox as below :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    if (window.opener){
        document.getElementById("from_date1").value = " 
           <%=Request.QueryString("indate")%>";

        document.getElementById("to_date1").value = <%=Request.QueryString("outdate") %>;
    }
</script>
```

Please help to make it correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I got the question right, but I will take a swing at it anyway. Wouldn't it be possible to call the popup with an extra attribute in the url? ie: pop=1, and then only append the values if this value is 1.

update_status.asp:

```
var myWindow = window.open("rateadd.aspx?pop1&loggedin=yes&indate=<%=indate%>&outdate=<%=outdate%>&curr=" , "", "width=1200,height=600,toolbars=no,scrollbars,resizeable=no,left=50,top=50");
```

Rate_Add.aspx:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<%if request("pop") = "1" then%>
        if (window.opener){
            document.getElementById("from_date1").value = " 
               <%=Request.QueryString("indate")%>";

            document.getElementById("to_date1").value = <%=Request.QueryString("outdate") %>;
        }
<%end if%>
    </script>
```

Comment: sir I appreciate your help as you got my problem the exact way I wanted to convey but after applying your code my textbox fields 'from_date1' and 'to_date1' are still empty even when I assign them with querystrings. Am I retrieving the values from querystrings the right way? I am doing exactly the way it was explained in the syntax.

Comment: If your script is at the beginning of the page then it tries to access a field that was not written to the page yet. Try to place it at the end of the page and let me know if it works better.
You can also get rid of the JS all together and simply apply the value directly to the element with ASP. ie: <input type="text" id="from_date1" name="from_date1" value="<%=request("indate")%>" />

Comment: Yes sir, it worked. Thank you very much for your time, sir.